# Android view model class has no zero argument constructor,Instantiation Exception in fragment

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-room, viewmodel

i have a view model class and i need to instantiate it in a fragment.
But I am getting :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.project.favourites.FavViewModel
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.project.favourites.FavViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
```

This is the line causing crash:

```
favViewModel= new ViewModelProvider(this).get(FavViewModel.class); 
(This line is within onViewCreated in fragment)
```

pls help!!!!!

Below is FavViewModel Class

```
public class FavViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private FavRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<FavItem>> allFav;

    public FavViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository=new FavRepository(application);
        allFav=repository.getAllFav();
    }


    public void insert(FavItem favItem){
        repository.insert(favItem);
    }

    public void delete(FavItem favItem){
        repository.delete(favItem);
    }

    public void deleteAll(){
        repository.deleteAll();
    }
    public LiveData<List<FavItem>> getAllFav(){
        return allFav;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of `FavViewModel'

Comment: @Vishnu added the code of FavViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this...

Initialise `ViewModel` like this. You need to also pass `ViewModelFactory` with `ViewModelProvider` constructor.

```
favViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
                new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getApplication())).get(FavViewModel.class);
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: @Vishu thanks! this worked!   only thing is it will be   getActivity().getApplication()

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate your model class with below annotation

**`@NoArgsConstructor`**

You will get more idea about lombok , NoArgsConstructor and many more annotations using this link[**`lombok`**](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor)